# Public and private dns zone using the same domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, bind

I'm trying to figure out whether i can use the same domain name for a host with both private and publics ips, where the public ip will be resolved if the private ip is not available.

in a non-aws environment, in DNS is it possible to all of the following:

1. return an internal ip from a private zone (test.com) record named my.test.com, when queried internally (intranet)
2. if the record is not found above - return an external ip from a public zone (test.com) record named my.test.com, when queried internally (intranet). This is not used for fail over /fault detection.
3. return an external ip from a public zone record named my.test.com when queried externally (internet)

This is possible from within route53/aws but how can this be done in a non-aws environment? If so, how is it done? especially step #2.

Answer (score 0):

It is a fairly common feature for a DNS server to have the capability to provide different sets of DNS information, usually selected by the source address of the DNS request. This is often called https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS when the scope is internal versus external queries and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoDNS or similar solutions exist when (many) different scopes must each get different DNS information.

Failure detection is not a native DNS feature.

But it is fairly common to have a (failing) health check for a service trigger updates to DNS records as a (global) load balancing and fail-over strategy. That is neither invented by nor exclusive to AWS services.  You'll find either custom solutions built around (proprietary) solution (such as for example the F5 BIG-IP DNS)  or more conventional monitoring scripts that make use of a DNS servers API whenever an alert is triggered.

Comment: I wonder how AWS handles step #2, where if  the record is not found in your private dns server, it goes to the internet public dns server for the same name. do you happen to know how they get this done? split horizon dns does not handle this? I'm not actually trying to handle failover in this case. just if the record doesn't exist, then lookup in public dns servers.

Comment: With most DNS server software available you would need to have the entire zone copied to the server that *believes* being authoritative for the zone. AWS handles the #2 by having a custom DNS server. (Of course you could write one, too.)